# Whether to copy or extend megaprotouser or metaprotouser to integrate liftweb with existing database

Tags: scala, lift

I am working on a proof of concept to show work the benefits of lift over MS MVC, so I am working on having liftweb integrate with an existing DB.

I would like to re-use what I can, but the user object needs to be modified, as there are behavior changes and I need to add and remove some attributes.

Would it make more sense to extend Mega or meta proto user or just copy the class and modify it under a new name, and just use that in my project?

If I modified it I could just add some new traits to change the behavior, but I need to change what is used to login as email isn't used.

In java I could use an aspect (AOP) to do this, and I think there may be a similar way in scala, but I am not certain.

I am integrating with MSSQL, so I expect it would be best to use mapper instead of record for this integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala runs on the JVM, so AOP techniques still work. But what most people find is that Scala's language features usually provide a cleaner and simpler way to accomplish their goals than AOP.

You can probably accomplish what you want by simply extending `MegaProtoUser`/`MetaMegaProtoUser` and overriding the methods you wish to change. For example, you can override `def findUserByUserName(username: String)` to search by a username field instead of email address.  The proto classes are designed for this sort of customization.

If you find yourself wanting to change so much that you want to copy/paste the whole thing, at that point I'd recommend just writing your own user classes, or using something that better fits your needs. There's nothing magical about the proto classes; they are simply there to give you a starting point. Plus, there are things that they do that would be bad form in production code (namely putting HTML in the model code).

[Tim Perret](http://timperrett.com/) said it best in [Lift in Action](http://www.manning.com/perrett/):

> The Proto-series traits are a starting point, not an ending solution.
>   In many ways, they’re similar to Rails’ scaffolding: they boost
>   productivity in the short term, but in the long term you’ll outgrow
>   them and gradually factor them out of your application, either by
>   replacing with your own code or perhaps with code from some plugin
>   or library.

Speaking of Tim and plugins, he wrote [lift-shiro](https://github.com/timperrett/lift-shiro), which integrates Lift with [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/). That may also be worth checking out.

Comment: Since this is just a proof-of-concept, anything I can reuse would be great, but I may try to override and see how much I can get it to work as I need, since I have to get it to conform to the data schema that already exists, and may just do a great deal with raw sql in the mapping.

Comment: I missed the bit about already having a schema to represent users. You may have bigger problems, unless you happen to store passwords the same way `MappedPassword` expects them to be stored. Maybe copying `mapper.ProtoUser` and bending it to your will would be best, then.

Comment: That is what I am thinking, as the passwords will be a problem.  I am leaning strongly toward the copy and bend approach.